# <fb:add-to-timeline show-faces="true"></fb:add-to-timeline> does not display

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-timeline

Is it normal for `<fb:add-to-timeline show-faces="true"></fb:add-to-timeline>` to display only for the app creator and not other users?

I am trying to test my app with my girlfriends account and

1. Permission Dialog/page  is still the old one
2. No asking for permissions to "add activity"
3. add-to-timeline displays "error occurred please try again later" or blank (random)

The other account I am testing on also has Timeline enabled.

Comment: Can your test server be accessed by Facebook.com servers?  I had same problem (actually, it would load on page for a second or two and take up some screen real estate, then it would collapse to nothing).

Comment: same thing here, both my tests are from the same computer ... and it displays ok when it's accessed from developers account, i guess it's still not released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Timeline hasn't been rolled out officially, you need to add the Facebook users to your app as testers. In the Developer App under Roles for your app, add your girlfriend's account. She will receive a notification. Once she accepts, she should be able to test your Open Graph app.

Hope this helps.